# bootstrap column to fit width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I hope this image can help me describe what I mean. I want to make the arrow and the boxes inline without the vacant space on the right. you can notice that the left most box is alligned on the white box on top, that is also what I want to achieve in the right. I will attach my code so you can see how did I do this.

Note: I updated the image above. There is a white box on top and under this 4 boxes. I need to align the eplay box to the white box above it and under it. also align the slide show demo box on the white box above and below it. Plus evenly space and size. And after eplay demo, theatre script demo, and audio speech demo box I need to put an arrow image in between. like this image below but need the right side box align to the top white box and under it.

[image]

```
        <!--===================DEMOS ==================-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 container-nopads" style="">

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 " >
                <div class="demo-box col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="demo-pdf">
                    <a href="/versebuster2/eplay/eplay-demo.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        <h4><strong>ePlay Demo</strong></h4><br><br><br>
                        <img src="images/hovers/pdf-512.png" >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 container-nopads" style="">
                <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>              

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 " >
                <div class="demo-box col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="demo-doc">
                    <h4><strong>Theatre Script Demo</strong></h4><br><br>
                    <img src="images/hovers/doc-512.png" class="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 container-nopads" style="">
                <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>              

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 " >
                <div class="demo-box col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="demo-mp3">
                    <h4><strong>Audio Speech Demo</strong></h4><br><br>
                    <img src="images/hovers/mp3-512.png" class="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1  col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 container-nopads" style="">
                <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="img-responsive" >
            </div>              

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 " >
                <div class="demo-box col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="demo-pdf">
                    <a href="data/pdf/ePlayPPPDemo.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; ">
                        <h4><strong>Slide Show Demo</strong></h4><br><br><br>
                        <img src="images/hovers/pdf-512.png" class="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--===================END DEMOS ==================-->
```

Comment: you can simply use `col-md-3` and use `::after` for arrow-img, that will be more easy for you.

Comment: use `row-fluid` instead of simple `row` class

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay i tried using the ::after but the image is dropping in the second line.

Comment: @propaganja  and JSFiddle ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay https://jsfiddle.net/mbktv6vq/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.col-md-3` class for this case:

```css
.col-md-3 .inner {margin: 5px; background: #99f; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="inner">Four</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: yes, this is a good answer but on the left most and the right most side I want it to be sticking and no padding or margin on each side.

Comment: You don't want spaces between them? Give a negative margin!

Comment: @propaganja That's your fix: `.col-md-3 .inner {margin: 5px -15px;}`

Comment: I need the spaces between those boxes but I don't want the space on the 1st box from its left. and the fourth box I don't need the space on its right. as you can see the illustration

Comment: @propaganja It was that way. Have a look.

Comment: I edited my post and posted the code you suggested but there is still space on the first box on its left. also there is still space on the 4rth box on its right side. I want it to be align from the top white box.

Comment: your answer has spaces space on the left side of the 1st box and space on the right side of the 4rth box. I have edit my question and the picture that I provided. tnx